# fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php

This is my first question so excuse me if i do something wrong! I'm trying  my best!

So i got this simple code

```
    <?php 
$fn = "file.txt"; 
$file = fopen($fn, "w+"); 
$size = filesize($fn); 

if($_POST['addition']) fwrite($file, $_POST['addition']); 

$text = fread($file, $size); 
fclose($file); 
?> 
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="addition" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('file.txt');?>"/> 
<input type="submit"/> 
</form>

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//<?php echo file_get_contents('file.txt');?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It works perfectly, just one small problem...

## Problem

The script works fine but the problem is that it outputs a error:

> Warning: fread() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u799303375/public_html/beta/private/Test/test.php on line 8

I have no clue how to fix this

## What i already tried

1. I tried removing the $size, didn't work, it expects 2 strings only gets 1.
2. Nothing yet...

Help me, if you need a working example just ask not included right now!

Comment: can't see how this code would issue that error. do you perhaps have a cached version of the file being hit by the server, or haven't updated the server's version?

Comment: Did you echo `$fn` and `$size` to make sure they're populated?

Comment: Try `var_dump($size);`, what do you get? Is `$size` defined?

Comment: Do you guys need a working example so you can see it yourself?

Comment: @PoeltjesHotel We need the values of $size and $fn

Comment: @KevinPei It outputs `int(0)`

Comment: @PoeltjesHotel Are you sure `file.txt` exists? That output indicates that the file has a size of 0...

Comment: @PoeltjesHotel Why do you need the `$text` variable as its not used in your code?

Comment: fopen in w+ would truncate the file to 0 length...

Comment: What do you mean a working example? If you know how to make it work without the warning, why did you ask on SO?

Comment: @KevinPei `fopen` is supposed to create the file if it does not exist

Comment: @JacquesMarais Ty! I don't know why i added that line, it worked thanks so munch!

Comment: It's fixed i had to remove one line! :-)

Comment: Great to hear... still doesn't explain why it didn't work in the first place though

Comment: @KevinPein It worked, the error just appeared, still don't know why but it works!

Comment: Heh, I got `Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in C:\nginx\html\test.php on line 8` running that same code..

Comment: I have no clue lol... @KevinPei

Comment: Wow my first question +25 thanks everyone :P

Comment: Best first question IMO so far , self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

By the PHP documentation, the fopen($fn, "w+") sets the file pointer to the beginning of the file and truncates the file to zero length. My assumption is that fread is not accepting a file size of 0 (zero) as a valid parameter value.

From your code snippet is looks like you are trying to append to this file. You might want to try a different fopen mode such as "a+". This will open the file for reading and writing, set the pointer at the end of the file. If the file doesn't exist, it will attempt to create it.

If you want the read the entire contents of the file (which it looks like you are trying to do); the fread documentation recommends to use file_get_contents() command. After you you write to the file and close it try the following command:

$text = file_get_contents($fn);

From your code snippet though, this doesn't look like it really is necessary.

Comment: Or simply don't read from a file where you already know the contents. Instead, keep a buffer of stuff that you are going to write to the file, and then save the file with that contents and set `$text` to the same buffer.

Answer (score 0):

fread() expects resource and int

```
string fread ( resource $handle , int $length )
```

Have you checked your $size parameter?
It could be FALSE. That may cause the error.

Comment: Thanks for your commed but it's fixed simply had to remove a line!