# Form empty itself without doing anything

Tags: php

Earlier today I asked a question about what I was doing wrong, I got this working but now I'm running into another problem with this script.

## Previously

The code gave a warning(), that's fixed now. You can read the post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787942/error-that-does-not-supposed-to-be-there)

## What's the problem?

The code automatically empty itself. When you refresh the page where the script is the text file is empty. I have no idea why...
This is the code

```
    <?php 
$fn = "file.txt"; 
$file = fopen($fn, "w+"); 
$size = filesize($fn); 

if($_POST['addition']) fwrite($file, $_POST['addition']); 

fclose($file); 
?> 
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="addition" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('file.txt');?>"/> 
<input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

I use this script to display a youtube video on my website, so I got to update it often.
You can find a working example of the script with this link: http://beta.martijnmelchers.nl/private/Test/test.php

## What have i tried?

I didn't try many because I couldn't find a solution for this on the internet and also not in the code. 
Please help me again! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `if($_POST['addition'])` to `if(!empnty($_POST['addition']))` does that do the trick for you?

Comment: You should start with the manual for `fopen` with `w+`: *Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.*

Comment: @Rizier123 That still does not do it. Check the example.

Comment: Oh thanks @jeroen make a answer of it i'll upvote it :)

Comment: I only need 1 more rep for 50 to comment lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with the `w+` option:

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning
>   of the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.

It looks like you want to replace all contents when a post is made, so the easiest solution is to put all file-handling calls in the POST condition:

```
// To avoid warnings, this is better.
// You can add your original condition after it if you need it.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  $file = fopen($fn, "w+"); 
  // not sure why you need this...
  // $size = filesize($fn);
  fwrite($file, $_POST['addition']);
  fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: @MartijnMelchers Don't worry about it :-)